# Why scrapy is not going to next page and only getting first page items?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Earlier I had one rule also i.e.

```
if domains in departments.keys():rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("?tab_value=all&search_query=%s&search_constraint=%s&Find=Find&pref_store=1801&ss=false&ic=d_d" %(keyword,departments.get(domains)),),restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]'),),callback='parse',follow=True),),
```

but I removed it as it was calling `parse` method which is not recommended.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from walmart_sample.items import WalmartSampleItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "my_spider"
    domains = ['All Departments']
    keyword = 'Laptop'
    departments = {"All Departments": "0", "Apparel": "5438", "Auto": "91083", "Baby": "5427", "Beauty": "1085666","Books": "3920", "Electronics": "3944", "Gifts": "1094765", "Grocery": "976759", "Health": "976760","Home": "4044", "Home Improvement": "1072864", "Jwelery": "3891", "Movies": "4096", "Music": "4104","Party": "2637", "Patio": "5428", "Pets": "5440", "Pharmacy": "5431", "Photo Center": "5426","Sports": "4125", "Toys": "4171", "Video Games": "2636"}
    allowed_domains = ['walmart.com']
    denied_domains = ['reviews.walmart.com','facebook.com','twitter.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for domain in self.domains:
            if domain in self.departments:
                url = 'http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query=%s&ic=16_0&Find=Find&search_constraint=%s' % (self.keyword, self.departments.get(domain))
                yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a[@class="prodLink ListItemLink"]/@href')
        for link in links:
            href = link.extract()
            yield Request('http://www.walmart.com/' + href, self.parse_data) 
        next_link = hxs.select('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]/@href').extract()
        if next_link:
            yield Request('http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do' + next_link, self.parse)
        else:
            print "last Page"                

    def parse_data(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items=[]
        walmart=WalmartSampleItem()
        walmart['Title']=hxs.select('//h1[@class="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Price']=hxs.select('//span[@class="bigPriceText1"]/text()').extract()+hxs.select('//span[@class="smallPriceText1"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Availability']=hxs.select('//span[@id="STORE_AVAIL"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Description']=hxs.select('//span[@class="ql-details-short-desc"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(walmart)
        return items
```

Comment: Please help me out as i'm struggling with this for past one week and tried too many things but not moving an inch.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're simply missing an "/a" step in your XPath for next page links:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a[@class="prodLink ListItemLink"]/@href')
        for link in links:
            href = link.extract()
            yield Request('http://www.walmart.com/' + href, self.parse_data)
        #
        #                                                    here
        #                                                      |
        #                                                      v
        next_link = hxs.select('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]/a/@href').extract()
        if next_link:
            # and as hxs.select() will return a list, you should select the first element
            yield Request('http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do' + next_link[0], self.parse)
        else:
            print "last Page"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! @paul t.
Need one more favour if possible,i was trying to fetch the ratings for each items which i'm extracting but couldn't find an appropriate xpath for them as on inspecting element it takes me to some image class.

Comment: It appears that the ratings are fetched via an additional HTTP request. For example for http://www.walmart.com//ip/HP-Refurbished-Winter-Blue-15.6-2000-2d19WM-Laptop-PC-with-AMD-E-300-Accelerated-Processor-4GB-Memory-320GB-Hard-Drive-and-Windows-8/33126518 , I see a call to http://walmart.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/1336/33126518/ratings.djs?format=embeddedhtml that contains Javascript instructions and data to display 4 out of 5 stars. You could open a new question on StackOverflow to get help.